# Is compiling LaTex in Android possible?

Tags: android, pdf, latex

I just wanna ask you is it possible to compile LaTex in Android app to export a simple PDF. I have not to write math formulas, just a letter.

Comment: Try https://www.mathjax.org, works in browsers haven't tried Android.

Comment: @QuentinUK: but "Android" is not a browser, right? Googling shows at least *ten* different ones on the first page alone.

Comment: I think the Chrome browser works well with Android. So you can test the LaTex online. Then use Blogger to make a document with MathJax. email link to recipient.http://quentinuk.blogspot.co.uk (can be shared privately) Or there're apps to convert pages to pdf.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=android

Comment: There is the [exTex](http://www.extex.org/) project; a TeX rewrite in Java, but it seems pretty dead.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old but just in case anyone has the same question eventually:

As a LilyPond user (LaTeX-like music notation/engraving software), which seems to have less users than LaTeX, I found my best bet to use Termux (you need to learn how to use the terminal a little bit, bash or zsh which are quite similar) and learn to use Neovim as an editor and LilyPond's (LaTeX's in your case) commands for the terminal. As for LaTeX, there's for sure more options like Acode as an editor (which supports syntax highlighting for LaTeX), and has a GUI.

If you go the Neovim/Vim/Emacs route, however, there'll sure be plugins to make both editing (with syntax highlighting and auto completion) and compiling in the same editor.

What is still an issue is probably the PDF viewer, because I haven't found a PDF viewer/editor that has auto-reload function (neither manual reload), so for now (unless someone tells me otherwise) for any PDF viewer/editor you'll need to close and reopen the file to check your changes.